# Colorbox implemented via Ether Builder throwing off div layout by 1 pixel

Tags: jquery, colorbox, pixel

So, within Catalyst I'm using Ether Builder which utilizes Colorbox as it's lightbox of choice  (convoluted enough?)  Any instance of an image that is to be opened in Colorbox throws the alignment of by 2px.  Example here: http://www.artifaktory.com/work/design/bollard/

Any ideas what could be happening?